# Iterate through dynamic JSON keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using:

```
JSON.parse(response.read_body)
```

Returned this hash:

```
{
    "stats": {
        "2012-10-31": 2637, 
        "2012-10-30": 2873, 
        "2012-12-14": 2894, 
        "2012-12-08": 2906, 
        "2012-12-09": 3357, 
        "2012-11-30": 4959
    }
}
```

The problem is that the Date keys can be any date value.

I want the sum of all values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're in Rails, you can just use [`Enumerable#sum`](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/sum):

```
JSON.parse(response.read_body)["stats"].values.sum
```

Comment: No problem. Learning the methods on Ruby/Rails's Enumerable is well worth the time.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Ruby Enumerable's  `reduce` method. I haven't done any error handling in my example, but you might need to deal with bad or missing data if this is coming from an API.

```
JSON.parse(response.read_body)["stats"].reduce 0 do |memo, kvp|
   memo + kvp.last
end
```

---

Edit:

Option 2 is more ninja:

```
JSON.parse(response.read_body)["stats"].values.reduce(&:+)
```